# Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method:

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, mono

I am getting the following build error in Xamarin.Forms.iOS

```
error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Boolean FluentValidation.ValidatorOptions::get_DisableAccessorCache()', referenced from the method 'FluentValidation.IRuleBuilderInitial`2<T,TType> TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.Validation.EnhancedAbstractValidator`1::RuleForProp(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<T,TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.Validation.ValidatableProperty`1<TType>>>)' in 'FluentValidation, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7de548da2fbae0f0'.
```

This only happens in ios, android is fine

Here is the full build log;

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core\TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
1>C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core\TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.165' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
1>C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core\TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'PCLStorage 1.0.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
1>C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core\TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'TruePotential.Objects.ForConsumers 2018.12.10.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
1>Helpers\Security\Cryptography.cs(100,34,100,36): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
1>  Fody: Fody (version 3.2.13.0 @ file:///C:/Users/davidp/.nuget/packages/fody/3.2.13/netclassictask/Fody.dll) Executing
1>  Fody: Searched for 'PropertyChanged'. Found: C:\Users\davidp\.nuget\packages\propertychanged.fody\2.5.14\build\..\netclassicweaver\PropertyChanged.Fody.dll
1>  Fody:   Finished Fody 294ms.
1>TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core -> C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.dll
1>  Fody:   Skipped Verifying assembly since it is disabled in configuration
1>Done building project "TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.csproj".
2>------ Build started: Project: TPMobile.Forms.Components.iOS, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>------ Build started: Project: TPMobile.ExampleProject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.ExampleProject\TPMobile.ExampleProject\TPMobile.ExampleProject.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
3>C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.ExampleProject\TPMobile.ExampleProject\TPMobile.ExampleProject.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.165' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
3>C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.ExampleProject\TPMobile.ExampleProject\TPMobile.ExampleProject.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'PCLStorage 1.0.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
3>C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.ExampleProject\TPMobile.ExampleProject\TPMobile.ExampleProject.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'TruePotential.Objects.ForConsumers 2018.12.10.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
3>ServiceReferences\ServiceFactory.cs(21,30,21,32): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
3>  Fody: Fody (version 3.2.13.0 @ file:///C:/Users/davidp/.nuget/packages/fody/3.2.13/netclassictask/Fody.dll) Executing
3>  Fody: Searched for 'PropertyChanged'. Found: C:\Users\davidp\.nuget\packages\propertychanged.fody\2.5.14\build\..\netclassicweaver\PropertyChanged.Fody.dll
3>  Fody:   Finished Fody 786ms.
3>TPMobile.ExampleProject -> C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.ExampleProject\TPMobile.ExampleProject\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\TPMobile.ExampleProject.dll
3>  Fody:   Skipped Verifying assembly since it is disabled in configuration
3>Done building project "TPMobile.ExampleProject.csproj".
2>  Connecting to Mac server 192.168.2.212...
2>C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.Forms.Components.iOS\Renderers\TPButtonRenderer.cs(24,22,24,35): warning CS0169: The field 'TPButtonRenderer.isWhiteButton' is never used
2>  TPMobile.Forms.Components.iOS -> C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.Forms.Components.iOS\bin\Debug\TPMobile.Forms.Components.iOS.dll
4>------ Build started: Project: TPMobile.ExampleProject.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhone ------
4>  Connecting to Mac server 192.168.2.212...
4>  Connecting to Mac server 192.168.2.212...
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "FluentValidation, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7de548da2fbae0f0" and "FluentValidation, Version=6.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". Choosing "FluentValidation, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7de548da2fbae0f0" arbitrarily.
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed". Choosing "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" arbitrarily.
4>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
4>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Globalization, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Globalization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Globalization, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
4>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Reflection, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Reflection, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Reflection, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
4>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
4>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
4>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Collections, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Collections, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
4>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
4>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Threading, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Threading, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Threading, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
4>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
4>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
4>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
4>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" from Version "6.0.0.0" [C:\Users\davidp\.nuget\packages\truepotential.objects.forconsumers\2018.12.10.1\lib\Xamarin.iOS\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to Version "11.0.0.0" [C:\Users\davidp\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\11.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "SkiaSharp, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756" from Version "1.59.0.0" [] to Version "1.60.0.0" [C:\Users\davidp\.nuget\packages\skiasharp\1.60.1\lib\Xamarin.iOS\SkiaSharp.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.IdentityModel" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Primitives\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll] to Version "4.5.0.3" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.ServiceModel.Http, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll] to Version "4.5.0.0" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.10.0" [] to Version "4.0.20.0" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Globalization, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Globalization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Globalization.dll] to Version "4.0.10.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades\System.Globalization.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Reflection, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Reflection\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Reflection.dll] to Version "4.0.10.0" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Threading.Tasks, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading.Tasks\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.Tasks.dll] to Version "4.0.10.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Diagnostics.Debug, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Debug\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll] to Version "4.0.10.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Threading, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.dll] to Version "4.0.10.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades\System.Threading.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Collections.Concurrent, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Collections.Concurrent\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll] to Version "4.0.10.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Collections, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Collections\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Collections.dll] to Version "4.0.10.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Facades\System.Collections.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime.Extensions, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll] to Version "4.0.10.0" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.
4>  TPMobile.ExampleProject.iOS -> C:\Dev\TPMobile\TPMobile.ExampleProject\TPMobile.ExampleProject.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\TPMobile.ExampleProject.iOS.exe
4>  Detected signing identity:
4>    Code Signing Key: "iPhone Developer: Mobile Developer (25UP79M7PR)" (B188F70014885E17572ADB858598D4805952188B)
4>    Provisioning Profile: "VS: WildCard Development" (ec2f1bdf-d784-4cef-bb5d-1c42c684fc47)
4>    Bundle Id: com.tpllp.hellotpmobile
4>    App Id: XSTU6BLQCD.com.tpllp.hellotpmobile
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(684,3): warning : Supported iPhone orientations are not matched pairs
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Boolean FluentValidation.ValidatorOptions::get_DisableAccessorCache()', referenced from the method 'FluentValidation.IRuleBuilderInitial`2<T,TType> TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.Validation.EnhancedAbstractValidator`1::RuleForProp(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<T,TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.Validation.ValidatableProperty`1<TType>>>)' in 'FluentValidation, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7de548da2fbae0f0'.
4>  --- inner exception
4>  Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'FluentValidation.IRuleBuilderInitial`2<T,TType> TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.Validation.EnhancedAbstractValidator`1::RuleForProp(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<T,TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.Validation.ValidatableProperty`1<TType>>>)' in assembly: 'TPMobile.Forms.Components.Core.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Boolean FluentValidation.ValidatorOptions::get_DisableAccessorCache()
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:1828 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00064] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:1532 
4>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.MobileMarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00001] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/MobileMarkStep.cs:140 
4>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.CoreMarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00001] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/CoreMarkStep.cs:228 
4>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchMarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00001] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/MonoTouch.Tuner/MonoTouchMarkStep.cs:98 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction (Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction instruction) [0x00048] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:1797 
4>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.CoreMarkStep.MarkInstruction (Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction instruction) [0x00042] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/CoreMarkStep.cs:223 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody (Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody body) [0x000a5] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:1775 
4>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchMarkStep.MarkMethodBody (Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody body) [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/MonoTouch.Tuner/MonoTouchMarkStep.cs:160 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition method) [0x0019d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:1623 
4>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.CoreMarkStep.ProcessMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition method) [0x00060] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/CoreMarkStep.cs:187 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue () [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:183 
4>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue () [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:185 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue () [0x00012] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:169 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process () [0x00146] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:131 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:72 
4>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.MobileMarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00001] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/MobileMarkStep.cs:33 
4>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.CoreMarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00017] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/CoreMarkStep.cs:32 
4>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchMarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0001d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/MonoTouch.Tuner/MonoTouchMarkStep.cs:36 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker/Pipeline.cs:127 
4>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.Linker.Process (MonoTouch.Tuner.LinkerOptions options, MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchLinkContext& context, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition]& assemblies) [0x000e0] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Tuning.cs:80 
4>  ---
4>  --- inner exception
4>  Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Boolean FluentValidation.ValidatorOptions::get_DisableAccessorCache()
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:1828 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00064] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:1532 
4>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.MobileMarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00001] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/MobileMarkStep.cs:140 
4>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.CoreMarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00001] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/CoreMarkStep.cs:228 
4>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchMarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00001] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/MonoTouch.Tuner/MonoTouchMarkStep.cs:98 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction (Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction instruction) [0x00048] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:1797 
4>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.CoreMarkStep.MarkInstruction (Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction instruction) [0x00042] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/CoreMarkStep.cs:223 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody (Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody body) [0x000a5] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:1775 
4>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchMarkStep.MarkMethodBody (Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody body) [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/MonoTouch.Tuner/MonoTouchMarkStep.cs:160 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition method) [0x0019d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:1623 
4>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.CoreMarkStep.ProcessMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition method) [0x00060] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/CoreMarkStep.cs:187 
4>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue () [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/external/linker/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:183 
4>  ---
4>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.Linker.Process (MonoTouch.Tuner.LinkerOptions options, MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchLinkContext& context, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition]& assemblies) [0x001f0] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Tuning.cs:99 
4>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Target.LinkAssemblies (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition]& assemblies, System.String output_dir, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] sharedCodeTargets) [0x00256] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Target.cs:522 
4>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Target.ManagedLink () [0x00720] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Target.cs:669 
4>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Target.ProcessAssemblies () [0x000c2] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Target.cs:873 
4>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Application.ProcessAssemblies () [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Application.cs:1411 
4>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Application.BuildManaged () [0x00001] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Application.cs:839 
4>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Application+<>c.<BuildAll>b__140_1 (Xamarin.Bundler.Application v) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Application.cs:787 
4>    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].ForEach (System.Action`1[T] action) [0x0001e] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 
4>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Application.BuildAll () [0x00050] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Application.cs:787 
4>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Driver.Main2 (System.String[] args) [0x00423] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/mtouch.cs:1402 
4>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/mtouch.cs:934 
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 1 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Additional**
If i turn linking off the solution complies

This leads me to adding to Additional mono args;

```
--linkskip=FluentValidation
```

Still no joy

Comment: Some suggestions:1.Delete bin and obj folder and rebuild your project. 2. Update and restart visual studio. 3.Reinstall `FluentValidation` and upgrade `Xamarin.Forms`. If the error still exist, you can refer [Can't resolve the reference '*'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt2101-cant-resolve-the-reference--referenced-from-the-method--in-).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am having this issue